# Consume a DELETE endpoint from Go

Tags: go

I am working in a Go project, and I need to perform some operations over an external API: [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and [DELETE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Currently I am using `net/http`, and I created a `&http.Client{}` to make GET and PUT. That is working as expected.

Now I need to perform a DELETE and I cannot find anything about it. Is it supported? Basically, I need to call a URL like this:

```
somedomain.com/theresource/:id
Method: DELETE
```

How can I perform that?

Comment: So how do you perform a `PUT` request? How making a `PUT` request would be different from making a `DELETE` one?

Comment: Just a guess, but if your code is not receiving the `DELETE` requests you might need to configure CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). What CORS does is basically send an `OPTIONS` request that asks for permission to send a `DELETE` request. That would happen if you are sending requests from the browser. You can try tools like `curl` or `postman` to make sure that an actual `DELETE` request is being sent. Also, if it turns out to be the problem, you can use a Go framework like Gorilla to properly handle CORS.

Comment: @Michał CORS is for client-side originated requests only. OP performs http requests from the server side application, hence CORS is not applicable.

Comment: @zerkms My bad, I thought he was serving it

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a small example of how to do it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func sendRequest() {
    // Request (DELETE http://www.example.com/bucket/sample)

    // Create client
    client := &http.Client{}

    // Create request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "http://www.example.com/bucket/sample", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Fetch Request
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read Response Body
    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Display Results
    fmt.Println("response Status : ", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers : ", resp.Header)
    fmt.Println("response Body : ", string(respBody))
}
```

Comment: I think this is a generally good answer, but I would recommend (for the sake of helping OP avoid issues down the line) changing just a few things: [close the response body](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/#anameclose_http_resp_bodyaclosinghttpresponsebody) and [close the connection once the request completes](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/#anameclose_http_connaclosinghttpconnections). There are a few cases where you wouldn't want to do these things in the same func, but I usually need to.

Comment: @Jonathan: some of those examples are incorrect, and you should follow the official documentation. Yes, you should always close the response body, but _always_ check the error first and defer it after; the response object is not guaranteed to be valid at all in the case of an error. Also you should generally _not_ close the request.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks for the feedback and for your thoughts. Good point about official documentation - I took a closer look at some of the other recommendations on that page and am thinking they were written pre-1.5. Sure, something that old may have some nuggets of helpful info, but not really appropriate to share in this setting when they don't fall in line with current official docs. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated the answer hope is better now.

Comment: If you use the method Do(request), it is not necessary that you close the body. **The request Body, if non-nil, will be closed by the underlying Transport, even on errors.** Comment from the go [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do)

Comment: You can also use `http.MethodDelete` constant instead of the string.